# C# Center the text in progress bar

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, progress-bar

I want to align the dynamic text on my progress bar.

Here is the code

```
using (var sf = new StringFormat()
        {
            Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
            LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center,
        }
    )
    progressBar1.CreateGraphics()
                .DrawString(message, new Font("Arial", (float)8.25, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(0, 0, 600, 480), sf);
```

The values `600,480` is the size of my application.
My progress bar location is `0,430`
Progress bar dimensions are `600,11`

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Your `StringFormat` is disposed before use.

Comment: Try to move last line into using block.

Comment: Whoops... It is in using block already. Format your code to avoid curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (var sf = new StringFormat()
{
    Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
    LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center,
})
{
    progressBar1.CreateGraphics()
        .DrawString(message,
            new Font("Arial",
                (float) 20, FontStyle.Regular),
            Brushes.Black,
            new Rectangle(0, 0, 600, 480), sf);
}
```

Comment: I tihnk I am using the same thing now.

Comment: okay. try to follow this [link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/94631-add-the-percent-into-a-progress-bar-updated/). i hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to measure the size of the string: [Graphics.MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Then use this simple formula:

```
containerWidth // width in pixels of the container
textWidth      // width of your string in pixels

margin = (containerWidth - textWidth) / 2;
```

You must offset the text from the left by `margin` pixels.